# Retrofit2：How send javaBean data to server? ( there are many files in this JavaBean )

Tags: retrofit2

It is my JavaBean data:

[image]

[image]

I use @Body

[image]

My service is springboot

[image]

I want to send data with JavaBean, but I failure, please Help me! thank you everybody

Comment: _"I want to send data with JavaBean, but I failure"_ What's the problem? Is there any stack trace about the error? If yes, please [edit] the question and post it here. And also do not post screenshots of the code as it's hard to understand, post codes in textual format instead.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I do not know how Sending files to the server in javaBean mode